# HTML5 Web Audio API - Recording Sound Temporary

Tags: html, web-audio-api, audio-recording

I'm currently creating a HTML5 music editing program.
I started with recording audio.
I figured out how to get access on microphon and so on.
Code from "Recorder.js" helped me a lot.

But instead of writing into an .wave file I want to create an temporary audiobuffer.
I got the Float32Array's from the inputtbuffer in "onaudioprocess" event and saved them all together in one Float32Array.
Now I have an Array with values, let's say from 3 Seconds of recording.
Now I want to create an Audiobuffer to play the sound I recorded (saved in that array).

In read the ([Webaudio API Specification])[1](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) but didn't found any possibility to create an new audiobuffer with an exisiting Float32Array.

Maybe I'm doing the recording wrong or I'm simply blind in reading.
Every other Questions I read were linking on Recorder.js, but I don't want to save a file first and then load it again.

Anyone knowing?
Would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite new to javascript but I think you're question is the same as what I was trying to do and now I have found the answer. Instead of calling the recorder.exportWAV function you call the recorder.getBuffer(getBufferCallback) function as you can see below. I hope this helps. it works for me.

```
function stopRecording() {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.getBuffer(getBufferCallback);

    //recorder.exportWAV(function(s) {  
        //source = window.URL.createObjectURL(s);
            //audio.src = source;
        //});
}

function getBufferCallback(buffers) {
    window.newSource = context.createBufferSource();
    window.buffers0 = buffers[0]; /*store the buffers in a variable so you can use them in future*/
    window.buffers1 = buffers[1];

    var newBuffer = context.createBuffer(2, window.buffers0.length, context.sampleRate);
    newBuffer.getChannelData(0).set(window.buffers0);
    newBuffer.getChannelData(1).set(window.buffers1);
    window.newSource.buffer = newBuffer;
    window.newSource.connect(context.destination);
    window.newSource.start(0);
}
```

Comment: Well... Simply thanks! It works! I just read "read-only" in the w3c Specification so I thought you can't manipulate. But as simple: Just create an buffer, call get Channeldate and set it with any array of data.... (you don't need the recorder.js) ... Thanks again...

Comment: Thanks great! Glad to hear it helped :) Have fun! :)